# Freemarker - Set and get variable name as empty string

Tags: freemarker

According to [freemarker FAQ](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_legal_variable_names) I can use any variable name with no limitation:

> FreeMarker has no limitations regarding the characters used in variable names, nor regarding the length of the variable names

How can I define in freemarker a variable name as empty string and reference it as

```
${}
```

Exception:

```
freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template "test.ftlh" in line 1, column 4:
Encountered "}", but was expecting one of:
    <STRING_LITERAL>
    <RAW_STRING>
    "false"
    "true"
    <INTEGER>
    <DECIMAL>
    "."
    "+"
    "-"
    "!"
    "["
    "("
    "{"
    <ID>
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.generateParseException(FMParser.java:5749)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.jj_consume_token(FMParser.java:5608)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.UnaryExpression(FMParser.java:658)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MultiplicativeExpression(FMParser.java:768)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.AdditiveExpression(FMParser.java:720)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.RangeExpression(FMParser.java:900)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.RelationalExpression(FMParser.java:848)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.EqualityExpression(FMParser.java:811)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.AndExpression(FMParser.java:967)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.OrExpression(FMParser.java:989)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Expression(FMParser.java:548)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.StringOutput(FMParser.java:1522)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContentElements(FMParser.java:3721)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Root(FMParser.java:4411)
    at freemarker.template.Template.<init>(Template.java:252)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.loadTemplate(TemplateCache.java:549)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplateInternal(TemplateCache.java:439)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:292)
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2654)
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2503)
    at com.FreemarkerTest.main(FreemarkerTest.java:46)
```

I also tried `${""}` by assigning empty variable but it ignores the value assigned:

```
<#assign  ""="aa">
${""}
```

Normally in a map I can assign a variable with empty string and get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While all kind of variable names are allowed (in the data-model at least), they aren't necessarily convenient to refer to. In this case you had to write `${.vars['']}`.

Note that the syntax is not `"${" VariableName "}"`, but the more generic `"${" Expression "}"`, so you can write things like `${x + 1}`, or even `${1 + 1}` (no variable reference in it at all). Thus `${}` contains an empty *expression* (which is invalid), not a variable reference of any kind.